# Generic return type in custom promise function

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript-generics

I've created a reusable function using generics that fetches data so every response matches the specified type. How can I implement a generic return type for this function that I can specify when I call the function? (Code block 2)

```
const fetcher = (url: string) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url, {
        headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
      });

      resolve(res.data);
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert(e.message);
      reject();
    }
  });
};
```

```
interface Test {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

fetcher("test.com").then((value: Test) => {
  //  Do something with value
});
```

The error I'm getting:

> Argument of type '(value: Test) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void | PromiseLike'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Test'. ts(2345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to make the `Promise` a `Promise<any>`.  The [`any` "type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) is not really a type at all; rather, it turns off type checking for values of that type.  This will allow you to annotate your `value` callback parameter to be `Test` without complaint from the compiler.

This is similar to the way the [`json()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) on the `Body` objects returned via the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is [typed i n TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/135c5082b19f6a3f664cd737e569acd6e87fb852/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L2557) to return a `Promise<any>`.  Not type safe at all, but it allows you to specify the type without fighting with the compiler:

```
const fetcher = (url: string) => {
  return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => { // <-- change on this line
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url, {
        headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
      });

      resolve(res.data);
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert(e.message);
      reject();
    }
  });
};


fetcher("example.com").then((value: Test) => {
  console.log(value.id.toFixed());
});
```

Of course, this lack of type safety means you, the developer (or any user of `fetcher()`) needs to be careful.  Nothing stops you from writing, for example:

```
interface Other {
  id: string;
}

fetcher("example.com").then((value: Other) => {
  console.log(value.id.toUpperCase());
});
```

Type annotations are [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript, and [`example.com`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) (there is a real `test.com` so I wouldn't use that for testing, fyi) won't see a difference between the two calls, so it can't know that the first call wants an `id` property of type `number` while the second wants an `id` property of type `string`.  So at least one of those would likely result in a runtime error.

There are more type-safe ways to write such things, but they will involve type guards that actually check your assumptions at runtime.  But if you just want to manually assert the type of the response and move on, `any` is probably the way to go.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcDkyqa+AUACYCmAxgDYJSVzUQB2a8AgrZbAFxwA3oh6wAFEgEJWATwCUAgG4Rg5OAF9SpFu3iZKMagAtecALxwxAVyi0BHKMFYBzOeYB8Q0nDiMYN1jhWSgB3OAAFHBBgNEoAHmkZdzEENBlWaktGNAhaRUoAGl9KACsaGDczT0FvHzgYKBkvOrqdDmKMCwQQhGB4InQAOmcDa1simpaWkwQqKDQBYU5qakowGAEAIgQwMFpgagQYVFYAehKc1k2NAtqW9TkAbi0pjtz8sWzB8iOEJ7uNMwjsZLJQ3JMptxeDBBghRDAxJRBiBKGg0AgRv9XowytQEVi6pofA9nupnqQnDBeJgEKs4AAVVHwCGqASsKwgABGvGePmOMB49gaTmcpK0+kMJigYk2lCQCHAPEGLBAmzkgxgJlYYjEijhVkoAkZHEq1VqbVySNoEGcuv1SNUGogADFgEhKOQxHJ-iStJTqbSmAB5TWmFnkIWOFyPOCkTSkCXGXgyuUKvZIlVqjVanV62gGgQhqWm5rMNg5JXW215g2DR0wCAAVV2vAAwqlKF6ff8gA)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but sadly my linting won't allow any types :{
If you really think this is the only way I will confront my project manager about the linting.

Comment: It's not "the only way", it's the way that's consistent with TypeScript's libraries for dealing with JSON-type output. `JSON.parse()` returns `any`; `(await fetch("")).json()` returns `Promise<any>`; your `axios.get()` is returning `AxiosResponse<any>`. If you don't want `any` but don't want to write a bunch of runtime checks, you will need to do something else equally type-unsafe, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/PmLMkW). Personally I don't see that as much better. If you're allowed to *use* `any` (like `axios.get()`) but not *write* `any`, then maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/4w1MKw)? ‍♂️